# Is there a capability difference between 3D Touch and Force Touch?

Tags: multi-touch

[Wired claims](http://www.wired.com/2015/09/what-is-the-difference-between-apple-iphone-3d-touch-and-force-touch/) that there is a difference because 3D Touch can detect levels of pressure, but in my experience Force Touch can as well.

For example, pressing the fast forward button in QuickTime with more or less force will switch between 2x, 4x, 8x etc. speed.

Is there any capability difference between the two haptic/Taptic features?

Answer (score 2):

This is a lot like asking if there's a difference between a Nissan Leaf and a Maxima. Both are cars, they seat 4 people, and they move around. The technology powering them though, is radically different. [Wikipeadia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_Touch) has the 3D Touch redirect to the Force Touch page, which is misleading (and incorrect). [This article](http://www.redmondpie.com/apples-3d-touch-vs-force-touch-vs-multi-touch-compared/) does a slightly better job explaining it, though it sort of steps on its own tail. Basically, Force Touch reacts based on the actual force (hard, medium, soft) where's de 3D Touch reacts based on the *kind* of touch (or tap): quick, prolonged, etc.

**EDIT:**

On second reading, you ask more about capability than implementation. 3D touch is definitely more sensitive than Force Touch, but with only the 6S just rolling out, we'll need to wait and see what Apple chooses to do with this enhanced capability.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way the quantify the difference in sensitivity? When I Force Touch a word in OS X I can vary the size of the popover with *many* degrees of force.

Comment: Not being an Apple engineer, I don't know C=. My guess is that by 'more accurate' Apple means they re-wrote some drivers or calibration software. Again, this is a misleading way to think about it - while Apple claims this is all based on how hard you push, in my experience 3D touch uses both force and time to determine what sort of input you gave.